# Python 2.7 argsparse with a path as args

Tags: python-2.7, filepath, argparse

I want to give my program a path to a file but it doesnot like it if there is a / included. How can I convince python that my path is only 1 argument

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Change the option prefix characters',prefix_chars='-+/',)
    parser.add_argument('-f', action='store', dest='PathtoFile',help='PathtoFile')
    print parser.parse_args()
```

it works without /

```
argsparse.py -f banana    ->    Namespace(PathtoFile='banana')
```

Any of those result in expect one argument

```
argsparse.py -f /home/user/banana 
argsparse.py -f '/home/user/banana'
argsparse.py -f '//home//user//banana'
argsparse.py -f "/home/user/banana"
argsparse.py -f "//home//user//banana"
```

->

```
usage: argsparse.py [-h] [-f PATHTOFILE]
argsparse.py: error: argument -f: expected one argument
```

UPDATE: Thanks match I forgot I added / as a prefix
Change

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Change the option prefix characters',prefix_chars='-+/',)
```

to

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Change the option prefix characters',prefix_chars='-+',)
```

Comment: I do not think that you need to action option. Remove the prefix_char option.  That is what is causing the error.

Comment: I don't know anything about python, but this looks suspicious: `prefix_chars='-+/'`. It looks like the `/` is set as a prefix character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `prefix_chars='-+/'` - this tells argparse that those characters are what mark out the command flags.

So your code is seeing `/` as equivalent to `-` and reading it as if you'd typed:

`argsparse.py -f -home/user/banana`

This means that `-f` has not been given an argument. Remove the `prefix_chars` and it should work properly.